# If a definite integral represents the area under the curve, why is $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln|\sin x| \, dx = -\pi \ln(2)/2$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I just noticed that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln|\sin x| \, dx = -\pi \ln(2)/2$ and my question is why is the area in this case a negative number?

Comment: It's the [signed area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral), the parts below the y-axis count with a negative sign.

Comment: A definite integral does not represent the area under the curve, but rather the **signed** area under the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Riemann-integrable and if $f \le 0$ on $[a,b]$, then the area between the curve and the x - axis is given by

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right|.$$

Answer (score 1):

The definite integral $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ represents the area under the graph of $f$ is $f$ is a **positive** function. Here the integrand is negative and the integral is the negative of the area between the graph and the $x-$ axis.